# How do I rerun something until succeed in the background with pipe in linux command line?

Tags: linux

Story: I'm following this guide to setup my geth node:

https://github.com/enthusiastics/bsc-archive-snapshot/blob/master/build_archive_node.sh

However, for this code chunk

```
# Query S3 for all archives and download them in parallel to a new zfs dataset.
while IFS= read -r FILE_NAME; do
  ZFS_NAME=$(echo "$FILE_NAME" | cut -d'.' -f1)
  ARCHIVE_NAMES+=("$ZFS_NAME")
  zfs create -o "mountpoint=/$ZFS_NAME" "tank/$ZFS_NAME"
  bash -c "cd /$ZFS_NAME && aws s3 cp --request-payer=requester '$S3_BUCKET_PATH/bsc/$FILE_NAME' - | /zstd/zstd --long=30 -d | tar -xf -" &
done <<<"$(aws s3 ls --request-payer=requester "$S3_BUCKET_PATH/bsc/" | cut -d' ' -f4)"
```

To be exact for the following line

```
bash -c "cd /$ZFS_NAME && aws s3 cp --request-payer=requester '$S3_BUCKET_PATH/bsc/$FILE_NAME' - | /zstd/zstd --long=30 -d | tar -xf -" &
```

some of instance would results in broken pipe, but a automatic restart could help. So I want to rewrite the code so that it automatically retries until the above line is succeeded. I researched a bit and found the `until do done` method. Example

```
until passwd ; do  echo "Try again" ;  done;
```

However, I could not succeed in incorporating the above idea into the GitHub code. I try to rewrite it as:

```
  bash -c "cd /$ZFS_NAME && until aws s3 cp --request-payer=requester '$S3_BUCKET_PATH/bsc/$FILE_NAME' - | /zstd/zstd --long=30 -d | tar -xf - ; do  echo "Try again" ;  done;" &
```

But it does not work... I test it on the minimum code:

```
until passwd | echo "randompipe" ; do  echo "Try again" ;  done;
```

it didn't run passwd until succeed

Comment: The pipeline `passwd | echo "succeed"` returns the exit code for the last command in the pipeline -- here `echo "succeed"` will always test `true`. It sounds like you want something like `until passwd; do echo "try again"; done; echo "succeed"`

Comment: ah... i'm very sorry that "succeed", has caused confusion .... actually, what i want is something like : `until (aws s3 cp --request-payer=requester '$S3_BUCKET_PATH/bsc/$FILE_NAME' - | /zstd/zstd --long=30 -d | tar -xf -) ; do  echo "Try again" ;  done;` I could not get it working.... I want the system to keep trying aws s3 cp until there is no broken pipe. I was using `until passwd | echo "randompipe" ; do  echo "Try again" ;  done;` to demonstrate a simplest example